# Iterated integral, vertically/horizontally simple

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Topic: Iterated integrals:
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ bounded by $x+y^2=0, y-x=6$ and let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous

**(1) is D vertically and/or horizontally simple?**

**(2) Calculate the area of D.**
So what I did was the following,
for (1) I have calculated the intersection points by
$$y^2=-x, y=x+6$$
$(x+6)²=-x,  \hspace{0.5cm}  x²+12x+36=-x, \hspace{1cm} x_1 = -4, x_2=-9$

then I have the region $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R²}: -9 \leq x \leq -4, \hspace{0.5cm}6+x \leq y \leq \sqrt{-x} \}$

Are the boundaries for $y$ correct? So $6+x$ is continuous, and  $\sqrt{-x}$ is continuous on [-9,-4]. So would it make D vertically simple?

and on the other hand, I have

$y²=-x, y-6=x, \hspace{0.5cm} y²+y-6=0, y_{1}=2, y_{2}=-3$

so
$$D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R²}: -3 \leq y \leq 2, \hspace{0.5cm}-y^2 \leq x \leq y-6 \}$$
Are the boundaries for x correct? would from this follow that it is also horizontally simple?

now how can I calculate the area of D?
would it be $\int \int_{D} f(x,y) d(x,y)$?

Comment: Draw the region $D$, you'll see both of your decompositions are incorrect. When determining whether or not $D$ is simple, keep in mind that the bounding functions are not required to be smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the diagram. If you integrate wrt $y$ first, you will need to do it twice as for $-4 \leq x \leq 0, $ the area bound is parabola whereas for $-9 \leq x \leq -4,$ the area is bound below by the parabola and above by the plane.

[image]

So instead set it up wrt $x$ first. For the second one, your boundary is correct but what you have shown as lower bound of $x$ should be upper bound otherwise you will get negative value. It should be clear from the diagram.

$\displaystyle \int_{-3}^{2} \int_{y-6}^{-y^2} dx \, dy$

Comment: Thank you so much for the diagram! how would the integral look like if I wanted to first integrate wrt to y? I didn't quite understand what you meant by saying that I would need to do it twice? what can I say about horizontal/vertical simpleness?

Comment: if you integrate first wrt $y$, what will you put as lower and upper bound of $x$ in terms of $y$? It is not the same for all values of $x$. Between $x$ from $-4$ to $0$, both upper and lower bounds of $y$ will be given by parabola ($ - \sqrt{-x}$ to $\sqrt{-x}$) whereas between $-9$ and $-4$, it is given by between parabola and plane ($ - \sqrt{-x}$ and $x+6$).